# How can I search a List for a partial match of variables inside its listed elements, then return one variable from a found match?

Tags: c#

I have a custom list that contains custom classes that each contain 3 integer variables (x, y, height). I want to be able to search the listed elements for any that match both 'x,y' and then return 'height' in the instance I don't know what 'height' currently is, only the current x/y.

This is the custom class

```
public class ConstructionCoordinates


public int x;
public int y;
public int height;


public ConstructionCoordinates(int xCoord, int yCoord, int levelHeight)
{
    x = xCoord;
    y = yCoord;
    height = levelHeight;
}
```

This is the Custom List

```
public List<ConstructionCoordinates> constructionCoordList = new List<ConstructionCoordinates>();
```

Comment: Where is `a` defined? Is `a` height? Do you want to return a single instance of `ConstructionCoordinates` if `x` and `y` match?

Comment: Sorry a is the height, I will adjust the question. First time asking on this site.

Comment: Please indicate what you have tried and why those things don't work.

Comment: @JamesHill I need to return the 'height' of the instance found that matches a given x and y :)

Comment: @user8569348 it depends on what measurement you want to use in your height. If it is in pixels, em, rem or something else, you place the calculation inside the loop and return it as "height". If you're not converting it at all, "x" would be the same as "height".

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (ConstructionCoordinates constructionCoord in constructionCoordList) {
    if (constructionCoord.x == x && constructionCoord.y == y) {
        // Place your logic here
    }
}
```